# How to count the ponderated occurrences of each string accross the whole table and all columns with SQL?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

morning !

here are 3 tables :

materials :
lists all the materials available :

| material | max |
| --- | --- |
| animalfat | 30 |
| arrow1_broadhead | 40 |
| arrow2_smallgame | 40 |
| arrow3_poison | 8 |
| arrow4_fire | 8 |
| arrow5_dynamite | 8 |
| arrow6_tracking | 8 |
| cartridge_pistol1_fmj | 400 |
| cartridge_reapeter1_fmj | 200 |
| cartridge_revolver1_fmj | 400 |
| cartridge_revolver5_explosive | 10 |
| cartridge_rifle1_fmj | 200 |
| cartridge_rifle5_explosive | 10 |
| moonshine | 40 |
| shotshell1_pellets | 120 |

requirements :
lists all the products possible to craft from the materials and the needed quantities :

| requirementID | product | materialx | material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cartridge_revolver5_explosive | 4 | animalfat |
| 2 | cartridge_revolver5_explosive | 1 | cartridge_revolver1_fmj |
| 3 | cartridge_rifle5_explosive | 2 | animalfat |
| 4 | cartridge_rifle5_explosive | 2 | cartridge_rifle1_fmj |

equipment :
list the quantities of product to craft :

| equipment | equipmentx |
| --- | --- |
| cartridge_revolver5_explosive | 8 |
| cartridge_rifle5_explosive | 4 |

the query searched for is a query listing all the needed materials and the quantities needed to craft the quantity of products listed in the equipment table.

the output in this specific case has to be :

| material | materialx |
| --- | --- |
| animalfat | 40 |
| cartridge_revolver1_fmj | 8 |
| cartridge_rifle1_fmj | 8 |

Comment: The question is why do you have 4 columns with the same content?

Comment: thank for answering !  

because each are describing recipes pamphlets in a table with ingredients as entities and their respectives amounts.
each [row, entry] describes the entity to use to produce the given new entity output.
for instance to produce : cartridge_revolver_explosive you need 4x animalfat + 1x cartridge_revolver1_fmj and the ingredients needed could go up to 4 so 2 more materials.

Comment: yes i understand that but a  normalize structure where you have product_id, ingredient_id, quantidy would save a lot of sopace and could alos handle if you need 10 ingredients and it would also save space as you have only to save numners and not hole text which would reside in a separate table

Comment: thank for your answer, very interested in the normilized structure you stated. can you give the beginig of an example on how you would build this table because here the `material` table is the `ingredient_id` table where you have all the ingredients listed which can also sometimes be products and you have the `requirements` table which is the `product_id` table. maybe your are suggesting to build a table for each `product_id` containing the multiple `igredient_id` and their respectives needed quantity ? can you provide a screenshot link illustrating your suggested structure ?

Comment: You describe an assembly/manufacturing process type of database, one of the more difficult to design. It is a common topic. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join tables and aggregate:

```
SELECT material, Sum([materialx]*[equipmentx]) AS matsX
FROM requirements INNER JOIN equipment ON requirements.product = equipment.equipment
GROUP BY material;
```

However, should really have materialID and productID primary key fields and save those values as foreign keys into requirements table instead of text values. Include all 3 tables in query to retrieve related data.

Comment: thank for answering, here the `material` table is a separate table from the `requirements` table. in the `material` table (which is a a related table to the `requirements` table) each material is used as a record. can you provide the begining of an example of the structure your suggest with a screenshot link for instance ? thank for the sql code as well, tried and it returns 4x animalfat and another 2x animalfat for instance instead of adding them up.

Comment: What do you mean by "begining of an example of the structure"? My suggestion is based on the dataset shown in first image and is complete. If that is not your data structure, edit question. Should post a text table of raw data instead of image. You will use the UNION query in subsequent queries as you would a table to do aggregation - modified answer to add this instruction.

Comment: by begining of an example, the meaning was to avoid you to do the whole work of building the structure you are suggesting, just the begining to show the way. the dataset of the 1st image represents only the `requirements` (produducts, recipes) table. you previously stated that you suggest a `Normalized structure would be a related table where each material used is a record `, which is already the case if notice in the table tree the `materials` (ingredients) table, which is exactly that, so according to your requirements it was actually `constructed correctly`. will post the raw data of the

Comment: `material` table as you asked for as well. also very interested by the union query you suggested, could you provide one which would output the last intended output table in the question post with the subsequent table and the subsequent table structure you suggest as well ?

Comment: In your image, materials and quantity are in multiple fields (3 sets are shown). In a normalized data structure each material and quantity would be IN ITS OWN RECORD. There would not multiple materials in each record. If table is actually as shown in image, suggest you follow instructions in my answer.

Comment: could you give an example on how you would proceed to make this dataset for instance normalized ? maybe by writting the same product multiple times for each material needed ? is it what you mean by material and quantity in it s own record ?

Comment: The UNION dataset is an example of a normalized structure. Except instead of saving equipment and material names in related table, would be EquipmentID and MaterialID. Have you even built this UNION query yet and looked at result? This is a many-to-many relationship and that needs 3 tables: Materials, Equipment, EquipmentMaterials. The last is a "junction" table.

Comment: do you have a discord like that it s possible to progressively purpose you structures and you correct them as well ? so you mean that in these 3 tables : Materials, Equipment, EquipmentMaterials, (the last one being the result of a UNION 'junction' query), Materials would contain 2 fields [MaterialID, MaterialName], Equipment 2 fields as well [EquipmentID, EquipmentName], EquipmentMaterials the result of a UNION query linking the 2 tables where only the [MaterialName, EquipmentName] would output as a result. here is a one drive link of the database if you want to restructure it as an example :

Comment: [rdo_craft.accdb](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiUmCeW6ezhq-Fglh6AVgU5s03jB?e=OLULQ9), discord :  `acixcix0001`, `554454910645567498`

Comment: No, EquipmentMaterials would not be the result of a UNION query. It would be a table. UNION query does not link tables. The UNION query is only a means to handle your current data structure. The 3 tables I describe would replace your current structure and eliminate need for UNION. Perhaps you need to study an introductory tutorial book on Access to learn basics of relational database principles and Access functionality.

Comment: already aware that union query does not 'link' in the table relashionship meaning of access, but it was to advance that in a way it would gather some of the data together. already aware as well of the table relationship system in access, just wondering how in this case you are considering to organize the data otherwise.

Comment: the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) does not tell as well how to 'normilize' the database in this specific case this is for that the reason that the question was originally posted actually, to obtain proposition from knoledgeable and willingly to help database [enthusiasts, professionals]. if the answer to this original post was already know the question would not have been posted. but as it s noticeable this question was welcomed by a dislike as well by undoubtidely non elitist welcoming users of this website disliking without proposing a solution....

Comment: is it what you mean by the 2 distincts tables [replaced the database in the editable link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiUmCeW6ezhq-Fglh6AVgU5s03jB), and now how do you give the correct merging of the 2 table to make the correct recipes ?

Comment: also yes the query was built but did not returned the intended result as previously noticed in this 1sts comments : ` thank for the sql code as well, tried and it returns 4x animalfat and another 2x animalfat for instance instead of adding them up.` .and yes well aware that it s an sql code because it even the title of this post.

Comment: the issue with the query you suggested is that is returns 4x animalfat separated with 2x animalfat and the quatities are not multiplied by the quantities in the equipment table which should actually gives : ((4x animal fat from requirements) * (8x cartridge_revolver_explosive from equipment)) +( 2x animalfat from requirements) * (4x cartridge_rifle_explosive from equipment) = 40x animal fat. and it should do this for all the differents need materials.

Comment: Yes. Need to use UNION query in another query. Build UNION query then reference it in subsequent queries same as you would a table. Join to Equipment table and do calculations to multiply and aggregate. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: thank for answering, for less complex setups yes but in this case it would be interesting if you could provide an example of what sql structure is needed in this specific case

Comment: could you show a quick example of the tables setup you would plan to use to reference the [`ingredients`, `recipes`, `number of servings needed at a given time`(which will be fed by a form for instance)] for a query listing the `shopping list` ingredients to get afterwards ?

Comment: do you have an example templete of that type of database laying around to provide on which it would be possible to study how you did in this case ?

Comment: updated the table with the new design

Comment: No, I don't have db for that. Redesign is normalized. Consider using autonumber fields as keys instead of text. Now build aggregate query shown in my answer, only use your normalized table in place of UNION query.

Comment: tried to adapt your last purposed sql code to the current specific test database and no result comes out : ```SELECT material, Sum([equipmentx]*[materialsx]) AS matsX
FROM requirements INNER JOIN equipment ON requirements.product = equipment.equipment
GROUP BY material;```.  
how would you do to take the quantities `materialx` from `requirements` table,  
identify for which specific `product` they are used to build in the `requirement` table,  
identify these specific product in the `equipment` table,

Comment: multiply these (quantities `materialx`  from `requirements` table) * (quantities `eauipment x`  from `equipment` table),  
still group by materials.  
so each time it woul give for instance :  
4x animalfat (to buld cartridge_revolver_explosive) * 8x cartridge_revolver_explosive to build + 2x animalfat (to buld cartridge_rifle_explosive) * 8x cartridge_rifle_explosive to build = 40x animal fat (1st row of the ouput),  
then, 1x cartridge_revolver1_fmj (to buld cartridge_revolver_explosive)  * 8x cartridge_revolver_explosive to build = 8x cartridge_revolver_explosive (2nd row of the output)

Comment: 2x cartridge_rifle1_fmj (to buld cartridge_rifle_explosive) * 2x cartridge_rifle_explosive to build = 4x cartridge_revolver_explosive (3rd row of the output)

Comment: `Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'`

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiUmCeW6ezhq-Fglh6AVgU5s03jB

Comment: updated the question post as well for a clearer question.

Comment: I built tables to test queries and they work.

Comment: did you use the database linked in onedrive or the related screenshots ?
is your output the same as the intended output ?

Comment: I used data posted in question. Output is same as in your expected table.

Comment: could you update your answer with an sql code for last update with `equipmentx` replacing the `materialx` field in the `equipment` table ?
and update your whole answer to the updated question post ?

Comment: Done. Didn't realize I typed wrong name for the field when I built table.

Comment: what if you absolutely want the headers to be the same as the puoposed output as well [material, materialx] ?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: `Circular reference caused by alias \`materialx\` in query definition s SELECT list`

Comment: And you have your answer.

Comment: yes having one and the code allowing to workaround this error is different from yours but it does exist

Comment: So what is your workaround?

Comment: do you want it to be posted as an answer and be validated or do you want some additional time to purpose it and your answer to be validated ?

Comment: Post an answer if you have a preferred solution.

Comment: even if already having another answer, that also gives the header, you made efforts to help and your answer already solves the main objective so your answer will be marked as solution.